# Describe the following spaces $L^1$ & $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to practice my understanding of $L^1$ and $L^2$ spaces with the problem below.

> Given $\Omega = \{\omega_1,...,\omega_7 \} $ let's consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ where $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ the power set of $\Omega$, and also $P(\omega_5) = 1/3$ and $P(\omega_i)= 1/9$ for $i \neq 5$. Let $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a function defined as $X = (2,4,2,1,3,1,4)$ and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets
> $$
> B_1 = \{\omega_1, \omega_3\} \ \ B_2 = \{\omega_2,\omega_4\} \ \ B_3 = \{\omega_5, \omega_6, \omega_7\}
> $$
> Describe  $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P); L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P);L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P);L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$

---

I've done the following but I feel like I'm mixing some stuff:

$L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P) = \{ X \ \text{r.v.} | \int_{G}|X|^2dP < +\infty\ \forall G \in \mathcal{G}\} $
which translates on the integral being finite in each of $B_1,B_2,B_3$, but my question here is, it's a discrete r.v. right? So shouldn't it be a sum?, and in the end it would translate to $\sum_{i=1}^7 X^2(w_i) < + \infty $ since the probabilities are finite right?

Same for $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ but $\sum_{i=1}^7 X(\omega_i) < + \infty $ instead of the squared.

And I don't know the differences for $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any random variable $Z$ on $\Omega =\{\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_7\}$ we have $\int Z dP=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{7} Z(\omega_k) P(\omega_k)$. Also all random variables belong to $L^{p}(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$  for every $p$ since finite sums  real numbers are always finite.

$L^{p}(\Omega,\mathcal G,P)$ consists of all real functions measurable w.r.t $\mathcal G$ and these are real functions $Z$ such that $Z(\omega_1)=Z(\omega_3), Z(\omega_2)=Z(\omega_4)$ and $Z(\omega_5)=Z(\omega_6)=Z(\omega_7)$.

Comment: So should I see $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{G},P)$ as some sort of "quotient" space where if $X \in L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{G},P)$ then $X$ is constant restricted to the sets that generate the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: That is correct. @M. Navarro

Comment: Thanks! So it should look like $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P) = \{ X r.v. | X(\omega_1) = X(\omega_3); X(\omega_2) = X(\omega_4); X(\omega_5) = X(\omega_6) = X(\omega_7); \sum_{i=1}^7|X(\omega_i)|^pP(\omega_i) < \infty$

Comment: @M.Navarro No point in writing the last condition.  A finite sum of real numbers is always finite, so simply drop that condition.